# SSO authentication not working on cross-domain requests

Tags: reactjs, django, single-sign-on, djoser

I am trying to enable SSO on my website.
The backend is on Django hosted on a different domain and frontend is on React on a different domain.
The backend is making Djoser package to handle social authentication.
The sessionId which I receive in the form set-cookie header is not getting saved in browser cookies even though Access-Control-Allow-Credentials is true due to which SSO is failing.

The same is working if my backend and frontend are on the same domain.

Is there any solution to this?

I am expecting SSO authentication on cross domain architecture but it is failing because session Id is not getting saved in browser cookies even though Access-Control-Allow-Credentials were enabled.